# The projection $G\rightarrow G/H$ is a fibre bundle with structure group $N(H)/H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, fiber-bundles

Suppose that $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. Then it is well known that the projection
$$\pi:G\to G/H$$
has the structure of a locally trivial fibre bundle with fibre $H$. As pointed out in the comments, it is usually understood to be a principal $H$-bundle.

However, in Bredon's book, *Topology and Geometry*, chapter $2$, section $13$, the author's first exercise is to show that $\pi$ is a fibre bundle with structure group $N(H)/H$, where $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$?

> The question is why the structure group here is $N(H)/H$?

In particular this seems to be in contradiction to some of the discussion in the comments. The following is a copy of the relevant page from Bredon's book which contains all related informations (before this exercise, there is a detailed discussion of the construction of local trivializations):

[image]

[image]

Comment: By definition?${}{}$

Comment: @JCAA I can only find local trivializations that the structure group is $H$, I can not find the trivializations to get the desired $N(H)/H$. Can you give me some hints or some references? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know. I have seen the statement before and the authors treated it as trivial. I think one of the authors was Belolipetsky. It was something about automorphisms of 3-manifolds.

Comment: Inuyasha, perhaps you should give a reference in your question as to why you think the claim is true. In *Topology of Lie Groups* Mimura and Toda tell me that the projection $G\rightarrow G/H$ has the structure of a principal $H$-bundle.

Comment: @Tyrone This comes from an exercise in Bredon's book, Topology and Geometry, chapter 2, section 13, exercise one. It also appears in other books as exercise, but I found no hints or detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is true.  For example, consider $SU(2)\subseteq SU(3)$.  This gives the $SU(2)$-principal bundle $SU(2)\rightarrow SU(3)\rightarrow SU(3)/SU(2) = S^5$.  Now, $N(SU(2)) = U(2)$ and $N(SU(2))/SU(2) = S^1$.  If the structure group of this bundle reduces to $S^1$, then it comes from a principal $S^1$-bundle over $S^5$.  Since $H^2(S^5) = 0$, any such principal bundle is trivial, which implies the bundle $SU(2)\rightarrow SU(3)\rightarrow S^5$ is trivial.  But this bundle is not trivial since, e.g., $\pi_4(SU(2)\times S^5) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ while $\pi_4(SU(3)) = 0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I have two questions. First, in the third line you said that it comes from a principal $S^1$ bundle, is it the same way of construction of the associate bundle of vector bundle? Second, in the fourth line you said any such principal bundle is trivial, is it follows the argument by Euler characteristic class?  Thank you.

Comment: @Inuyasha:  In the third line, yes, that's what I was thinking.  That said, I didn't think through the details - maybe Bredon and I are having a terminology clash?  In the fourth line, yes.  What I'm thinking of is $\{S^1-\text{principal bundles over} M\} \leftrightarrow [M, BS^1] = [M, CP^\infty] \leftrightarrow H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ since $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.

Comment: (By the way, in general, given the choice between trusting Bredon or myself, I know which way I lean!  Still, I don't know why I wrote above doesn't contradict what Bredon writes, and I do agree that Bredon wrote what you said he wrote....)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think Bredon is constructing a *non-principal* fibre bundle with structure group $N(H)/H$ and fibre $H$. Inuyasha, please edit in some details and background into your question so that someone can answer it.

Comment: @Tyrone:  But aren't all fiber bundles associated to principal bundles?  (e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325343/principal-bundles-and-fibre-bundles)  And isn't the associated bundle to any trivial principal bundle itself trivial?  I still don't see how to revolve the conflict between my comment above and Bredon's claim.

Comment: @JasonDeVito under a reasonable definition all fibre bundles are associated to a principal bundle. I neither understand what Bredon is doing, I'm afraid, and I haven't had time to go through it yet. It could be a typo?

Comment: I searched the exercise in google and I found some related exercises. For example, Lie Groups by J.J. Duistermaat, Johan A.C. Kolk, page 128, exercise 2.6. It may be helpful since they look similar.

Comment: @Inuyasha, sorry I rewrote most of your question :P. I think you asked a good question.